# Best way to suffix value to a string if it matches a condition and generate a comma separated list of the values in a list

Tags: java, java-8, mapping, java-stream

What is the best way to do the below in Java 8.

I have a list of ColumnInfo objects,

ColumnInfo CLASS has below members

```
String name
Class<?> type
Object value
```

I want to iterate list of ColumnInfo objects and if any of them is of type String.class I want to suffix "IS A STRING" to the column name , for other columns I want to return column name as is, the return value should be a comma separated string. The comma separated string should maintain the order of items as is in the incoming List of ColumnInfo objects.

So, if I have column info objects as below

```
{order_code , Integer.class, 10}
{order_city, String.class ,"france"}
{is_valid, Boolean.class, true}
```

**expected output**

```
order_code, order_city IS A STRING, is_valid
```

**Below is my approach, Is there a better way to do this?**

```
String commaSepStr = columnInfos.stream()
            .map(f -> {
                String retValue = isString(f)? f.getName()+ " IS A STRING" : f.getName();
                return retValue;
            }).collect(Collectors.joining(" ,")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
String resultStr = columnInfoList.stream()
    .map(ci -> ci.getType() == String.class ? ci.getName() + " IS A STRING" : ci.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

You don't need to assign it to a variable and return. Rather you can directly return it. Also the implementation of the `isString` method seems not necessary to me since it can be done inline. So it is fair for me to keep this as the answer.